# JS SlideUp and SlideDown not working on table properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to Javascript, so please forgive me if this seems like a simple problem.

I am trying to do a simple toggle function between two buttons that slide the content i want displayed up and down, using Javascript. Unfortunately, the effect is only working on the first row of data that is displayed in my table.

Could someone spot what i need to do to make this function work for each table row?

Here is a link to my JSFiddle:
[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/coey235/mfwYS/1820/)

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("td[colspan=9]").find("p").hide();
  $("#less").hide();
  $("#more").click(function(event) {

    event.stopPropagation();
    var $target = $(event.target);

    if ($target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1) {
      $target.slideDown();
      $("#less").show();
      $("#more").hide();
    } else {
      $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideDown();
      $("#less").show();
      $("#more").hide();
    }

  });
  $("#less").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if ($target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1) {
      $target.slideUp();
      $("#more").show();
      $("#less").hide();
    } else {
      $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideUp();
      $("#more").show();
      $("#less").hide();
    }

  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 75%;
}
tr {
  border: 2px solid #AEAEAE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Name</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Age</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Info</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id=more>+</button>
      <button id=less>-</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Name</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Age</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Info</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id=more>+</button>
      <button id=less>-</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Name</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Age</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Info</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id=more>+</button>
      <button id=less>-</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you on advance for any help.

Comment: what browser is giving you trouble? Working fine in chrome and firefox for me.

Comment: You JS in your question is quite different to your JSFiddle link. Works fine for me on all rows.

Comment: I actually see you're trying to do different things completely in the code in your question compared to the code in your example link. Do you want them to expand/collapse on click of the row, or on click of the +/- buttons?

Comment: Problem is in duplicated ids - use classes (.less, .more).... ID must be unique.

Comment: sorry i updated the fiddle and forgot to save. i have now updated the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues in your snippet.

1: There are duplicate id element for more and less

2: you are binding click event on these duplicated id selectors which is making the whole logic of sliding up/ sliding down wrong

Try the below code.

I have changed the duplicate ids to class and done some changes to slid up.slide down and show more/less logic.

```js
$(function() {
  $("td[colspan=9]").find("p").hide();
  $(".more").hide();
  $(document).on("click",".more", function(event) {

    event.stopPropagation();
    var $target = $(event.target);

    if ($target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1) {
      $target.slideDown();
      $target.next(".less").show();
      $target.hide();
    } else {
      $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideDown();
      $target.next(".less").show();
      $target.hide();
    }

  });
   $(document).on("click",".less", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if ($target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1) {
      $target.slideUp();
      $target.prev(".more").show();
      $target.hide();
    } else {
      $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideUp();
      $target.prev(".more").show();
      $target.hide();
    }

  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 75%;
}
tr {
  border: 2px solid #AEAEAE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Name</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Age</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Info</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class=more>+</button>
      <button class=less>-</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Name</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Age</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Info</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class=more>+</button>
      <button class=less>-</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Name</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Age</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Info</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class=more>+</button>
      <button class=less>-</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @tCoe :) Glad to help

Comment: how would that be applied to a table that has the data returned from an SQL query?

Comment: okk , that means you are generating html dynamically, event delegation will be your friend then

Comment: @tCoe updated the code with event delegation on .more  and .less class click.

Comment: after i changed the "." to "#" it works great except one thing. on startup, the first row only displays the more button, but every addition row displays both. how do i hide the less button on the additional rows?

Comment: $(".more").not(":first").hide();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133095/discussion-between-tcoe-and-deep).